# Getting an output of 'None' but not sure what exactly is triggering it

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have a function to plot two histograms as well as a method to compute some stats from tables given to me in a homework problem. When I run this function in my jupyter notebook I am given the following output:

```
None                #Not quite sure where this came from
(26.54, 4269775.77) #This is calculated correctly

<histogram 1> #This is rendered correctly
<histogram 2> #This is also rendered correctly
```

whereas my expected output should simply be

```
(26.54, 4269775.77)

<histogram 1>
<histogram 2>
```

I've tried commenting out different lines to see if I can isolate the issue but to no avail. Below is my code that I am running which corresponds to the output above

```
def compute_statistics(age_and_salary_data):
    t = full_data
    age = t.column('Age')
    salary = t.column('Salary')
    age_and_salary_data = Table().with_columns('Age', age, 'Salary', salary)
    print(age_and_salary_data.hist('Age', bins = (np.arange(18,np.max(age)+1,1))))
    average_age = np.mean(age)
    average_salary = np.mean(salary)
    average_list = (np.round(average_age, 2), np.round(average_salary,2))
    return age_and_salary_data.hist('Salary', bins = np.arange(0,np.max(salary)+1, 1000000))
average_age = np.mean(full_data.column('Age'))
average_salary = np.mean(salary_data.column('Salary'))
average_list = (np.round(average_age, 2), np.round(average_salary, 2))
compute_statistics(full_data)
print(average_list)
```

When I run this through the grader I am met with the following as to why the answer I am getting the answer wrong.

```
>>> round(float(compute_statistics(full_data)[0]), 2) == 26.54
None
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

# Error: expected
#     True
# but got
#     Traceback (most recent call last):
#       ...
#     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Looks like `age_and_salary_data.hist()` doesn't return anything as your code seems to be assuming.

Comment: It should be though right? As I've set it as a variable for a table?

Comment: Actually it looks like `age_and_salary_data` is actually a list whose first element, at index `[0]`, has the value `None`.

Comment: That's interesting because it should be 28, `full_data` is a table given to us that we rendered

Comment: It's also interesting because I don't think I have anything in my code that is asking for a return of `age_and_salary_data.item(0)` or `age_and_salary_data[0]`. All of my returns are coming back as expected I just seem to have this None that insists on planting itself inside my answer

Comment: Try using `return age_and_salary_data.hist('Salary', bins = np.arange(0,np.max(salary)+1, 1000000))[1]` at the end of the `compute_statistics()` function.

Comment: Returns the following:

`None`

then a TypeError and then the histograms are correctly rendered again

Comment: Hmm, OK, the maybe it should be `return age_and_salary_data.hist('Salary', bins = np.arange(0,np.max(salary)+1, 1000000))[1][0]` which contains the value `26.54`,

Comment: Interestingly returns the same result

Comment: Where is the `Table` class defined? What does its `.hist` look like? Also, are you aware that `compute_statistics` *ignores* its parameter and instead computes a *new* table based off the *global* `full_data`?

Comment: @Karl: I'm _guessing_ `hist()` is a part of `matplotlib.pyplot`. Here's its [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Comment: @Karl table is part of a module `datascience` which I think is a compilation of many datascience related libraries. I also did see what you're talking about because I have that `t` variable which I went ahead and removed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kept playing around with the function and was able to get rid of the pesky None by removing the `print` statement in the function `compute_statistics` and rendering the histogram as a return just as with the other histogram. For reference:

```
def compute_statistics(age_and_salary_data):
    age = full_data.column('Age')
    salary = salary_data.column('Salary')
    age_and_salary_data = Table().with_columns('Age', age, 'Salary', salary)
    average_age = np.mean(age)
    average_salary = np.mean(salary)
    average_list = (np.round(average_age, 2), np.round(average_salary,2))
    return age_and_salary_data.hist('Salary', bins = np.arange(min(salary),max(salary)+1, 1000000)), age_and_salary_data.hist('Age', bins = (np.arange(min(age),max(age)+1,1)))
average_age = np.mean(full_data.column('Age'))
average_salary = np.mean(salary_data.column('Salary'))
average_list = (np.round(average_age, 2), np.round(average_salary, 2))
compute_statistics(full_data)
print(average_list)
```

While this has fixed my problem and I guess could be considered an answer I still am not sure why doing what I did worked versus having a print statement instead and any insight would be appreciated

Comment: This will still fail the test code, because it still `return`s the wrong value - now it will return `(None, None)`. The reason it "worked" is that a) using `print` has nothing to do with actually creating the histogram, and b) nothing in your code actually cares about the return value from `compute_statistics` - but the test code does.

Answer (score 0):

In your notebook: `compute_statistics(full_data)` is called, which `print`s one result from a `.hist` method, and then `return`s another. In both cases, the method returns `None`, so the `print` displays that, and then the `return`ed value is also None, but nothing in your code makes use of it. Then you `print(average_list)`, which gives you the last value in the console, and also you see the histograms.

The `.hist` method presumably produces the histograms as a side effect, and returns `None`, because there is no value to return.

```
round(float(compute_statistics(full_data)[0]), 2) == 26.54
```

This is what the testing code looks like. It is expecting to get the `average_list` values back when it calls `compute_statistics`, so that it can extract the average age, round it, and compare to the expected value. However, it receives `None` instead, which cannot be subscripted.

The test code does not care what you `print` at all. (I assume that inside the provided `datascience` library, the `.hist` method does some kind of tracking to make sure you made the expected calls to draw those histograms.)

Read the assignment spec again, and make sure you understand the difference between `return`ing values and `print`ing them.